# Why does the diagonal map yield a natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory

From pg. 72 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

[image]
[image]

**Question:** How does one know that this diagonal map is a natural transformation?

I'm assuming that the two functors involved are (i) the identity functor and (ii) the functor that sends objects $c$ to $c \times c$. Is this at least correct?

Comment: Your "is this at least correct?" is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
You are correct about the two functor involved; but you've only described their action on objects. Given an arrow $f:C\to D $, we can define an arrow $f\times f:C\times C \to D\times D$ using the universal property of $D\times D$. For this it suffices to find two arrows $C\times C \to D$, so we can take $fp_1$ and $fp_2$. Thus the arrow $f\times f$ must be such that $p_i(f\times f)=fp_i$. In the category of sets, for example, $f\times f$ is the arrow $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),f(y))$.

Now you can simply apply the definition of natural transformation : you need to check that the square 
$$
\begin{CD}C  @>{\delta_C}>>  C\times C \\ 
@V{f}VV @VV{f\times f}V \\
D  @>>{\delta_D}>  D\times D\end{CD}
$$
commutes. For this, you can compose with the projection $p_i$:
$$p_i\circ (f\times f)\circ \delta_C=f\circ p_i\circ \delta_C=f\circ 1_C=f=1_D\circ f=p_i\circ \delta_D\circ f,$$
and since the projections $p_i$ are jointly monic,
$$(f\times f)\circ \delta_C=\delta_D\circ f.$$

Comment: What justifies the very first part of the equality: $p_i\circ (f\times f)\circ \delta_C=f\circ p_i\circ \delta_C$?

Comment: @user1770201 I've edited my answer to explain that with more details.